# Serializing Object with Lists Takes Longer than serializing the lists

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I have a C# program whose purpose is to watch me play NES Tetris and calculate how badly the RNG is screwing me over. One of the side functions is that the program stores the board-state, score, level, and piece count. A FrameState object contains a few bytes, a few ints, and a 20x10 array of chars.

In one hour wasted playing Tetris, I generate about 100k frame states at 30/second.

It takes a long time to serialize these FrameState objects, and a much longer time to deserialize them. But it is very fast to serialize and deserialize the same amount of data as loose objects

Here is a repro. This repro stores about the same amount of data as 10 hours of Tetris.

If I store all of the separate Lists, and the Lists of arrays. It takes .75 seconds to serialize, and 2 seconds to deserialize total. This is the commented lines.

But if I put all of those into an object (Holder), it takes 8 seconds to serialize and 8 minutes to deserialize.

Now I could take advantage of that by deconstructing prior to serializing and reconstructing after. But I'm surprised by this behavior and wonder whether I've made some rookie mistake--being a rookie and all.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BitArrayTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [Serializable]
        private class Holder
        {
            public List<char[]> CharList { get; set; }
            public List<bool[]> Boollist { get; set; }
            public List<int> Intlist { get; set; }
            public List<byte> Bytelist { get; set; }
            public List<short> Shortlist { get; set; }
            public List<BitArray> Bitlist { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 200;

            List<char[]> charList = new List<char[]>();
            List<bool[]> boollist = new List<bool[]>();
            List<int> intlist = new List<int>();
            List<byte> bytelist = new List<byte>();
            List<short> shortlist = new List<short>();
            List<BitArray> bitlist = new List<BitArray>();

            byte b = 0;
            short s = 0;

            int runtime = 10 * 30 * 60 * 60;

            for (int j = 0; j < runtime; j++)
            {
                bool[] bools = new bool[size];
                char[] chars = new char[size];
                BitArray bits = new BitArray(size);

                intlist.Add(j);
                bytelist.Add(b++);
                shortlist.Add(s++);

                if (b == 255)
                    b = 0;
                if (s == short.MaxValue)
                    s = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        bools[i] = true;
                        bits[i] = true;
                        chars[i] = (char)i;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bools[i] = false;
                        bits[i] = false;
                        chars[i] = (char)i;
                    }
                }
                boollist.Add(bools);
                charList.Add(chars);
                bitlist.Add(bits);
            }

            string boolstr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\bools";
            string charstr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\chars";
            string bitsstr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\bits";
            string intsstr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\ints";
            string bytestr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\bytes";
            string shrtstr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\shorts";
            string holdstr = @"C:\Michaelp\Source\trash\holder";


            Holder holder = new Holder
            {
                CharList = charList,
                Boollist = boollist,
                Intlist = intlist,
                Bytelist = bytelist,
                Shortlist = shortlist,
                Bitlist = bitlist
            };

            Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            SerializeObject(holdstr, holder);
            //SerializeObject(boolstr, boollist);
            //SerializeObject(charstr, charList);
            //SerializeObject(bitsstr, bitlist);
            //SerializeObject(intsstr, intlist);
            //SerializeObject(bytestr, bytelist);
            //SerializeObject(shrtstr, shortlist);

            Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
            watch.Restart();

            Holder holder2 = Deserialize<Holder>(holdstr);

            //List<bool[]> boollist2 = Deserialize <List<bool[]>>(boolstr);
            //List<char[]> charList2 = Deserialize <List<char[]>>(charstr);
            //List<int> intlist2 = Deserialize <List<int>>(intsstr);
            //List<byte> bytelist2 = Deserialize <List<byte>>(bytestr);
            //List<short> shortlist2 = Deserialize <List<short>>(shrtstr);
            //List<BitArray> bitlist2 = Deserialize <List<BitArray>>(bitsstr);
            Debug.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }

        private static void SerializeObject<T>(string filename, T obj)
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            stream.Close();
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string filename)
        {
            //Open file.
            Stream streamRead = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryFormatter bfRead = new BinaryFormatter();

            //Deserailze file back to object.
            T newT = (T)bfRead.Deserialize(streamRead);

            streamRead.Close();

            return newT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, the best advice I can give you here is: stop using BinaryFormatter ([Ioger version](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html)). Is it an option to try protobuf-net or similar?

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Thanks, it would seem this is not an option. ProtoBuf throws "Nested or jagged lists, arrays and maps are not supported: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char[]]"

Comment: Also, it seems like my complaint might go away in .NET 5.0. I need to go back to work to see what framework the repro was in.

Comment: well, a List-of-string would work :)